# Moq Insert/Update with new Object initialization

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

```
public class UserService
{
    IUserRepo userRepo;

    UserService(IUserRepo repo)
    {
        userRepo = repo;
    }

    void AddUser(JsonData data)
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            Name = data.name,
            Number = data.Number
        };

        userRepo.Insert(user);

        int id = user.id;
    }
}
```

`id` is 0 when a unit test case is debugged, but when it is a proper call it returns proper primary key i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.

**Mock**

```
class TestCases
{
    Mock<IUserRepo> mockUserRepo = new Mock<IUserRepo>();

    [Test]      
    public void test1()
    {
        //Arrange
        JsonData obj = new JsonData()
        {
            Name = "Jane",
            Number = "0563722992"
        }

        User dumpUser= new User()
        {
            Name = "Def",
            Number = "8111"
        };

        mockUserRepo
            .Setup(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<User>()))
            .Callback(() => dumpUser.Id = 1);

        //Act
        UserService u = new UserService(mockUserRepo.Object);
        u.AddUser(obj);

        //Assert
    }
}
```

While debugging the unit test it seems that callback is unable to change the `id` to 1 when it passes through the method `Insert()`.

Can anybody help how to tackle with this issue?

Comment: You are changing the id of 'dumpUser', not the user created inside your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for

```
User dumpUser= new User()
{
    Name = "Def",
    Number = "8111"
};
```

As the method under test creates/initializes it's own instance within.

Capture the passed argument in the call back and update the desired member there

```
//...

userRepo
    .Setup(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<User>()))
    .Callback((User arg) => arg.Id = 1);

//...
```